# ChromeProxyService: Failed to evaluate expression how to solve?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, flutter-web

I'm debugging a code but every time I try to see the variable values it shows this message. does anyone know how to resolve?

Flutter 3.3.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 135454af32 (5 weeks ago) • 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
Engine • revision 3316dd8728
Tools • Dart 2.18.6 • DevTools 2.15.0

google chrome version 109.0.5414.75 64 bit

I searched the internet and it was telling me to update flutter to a version greater than 3.0 and google chrome to the newest version and even so it continues to give this error.  I tried to run the project in another browser but the same error message appears. in short, none of the solutions I've found to date allowed. I even formatted the computer and today I have Windows 11

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your code?

Comment: which part ? if the problem happens in any variable of the project